# Vertex AI CSV import of images from Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a data set on Cloud Storage Bucket. I [prepared & uploaded](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/prepare-data#csv_1) a .csv in Vertex AI Datasets with labels to each image in the Cloud Storage Bucket. Once it tries to import, I get the following message :

> Unable to import data due to errors.

When I click more details, I get the following error message repeated multiple times for different images :

> Error: Permission denied on gs://`originationBucket`/file (or it may not exist). Does x@y.com have permission to read? for: gs://`destinationBucket`/labels.csv line x "

When I verify the Storage Bucket, the files in question exist, and the AI Platform Service Agent email has an inherited permission on the Bucket.

I have tried setting permissions on both sides [as suggested in docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-add):
Storage Legacy Bucket Reader
Storage Legacy Object Reader
Storage Object Viewer

Here is the single row of data I tried to upload, in CSV format:

```
gs://ai_user_images/12-22-23submitted_review_1130-1218/Adams_dry.jpeg,adams_dry
```

Are there different roles I should use?

Comment: Hi @Phil Lucks,  I would like to suggest you check your CSV file with a text editor (Sublime Text, Geany, Pluma, etc.) and verify if there are double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the line. If there are any double quotes I would suggest you to remove the double quotes and then retry and check if it works.

Comment: Hi @Phil Lucks, Could you confirm if the above comment helped you or not ?

Comment: hi @SushmaJeerahalli, there are no formatting issues.  I updated my original post to include the single CSV row of data as my test.

Comment: Hi @Phil Lucks, it appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/?hl=en). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.